# How can I access the H264 stream from my IP-camera with "Motion"?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 15.04, camera, motion

**What is Motion?:** Motion is a deamon application which allows Linux users to record pictures of webcams and ipcams based on motion detection or time settings. A Tutorial how to set up the stable release can be found [here](http://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-motion-detection-webcam-ubuntu/). Here is the [Motion developer website and documentation](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion)

**My Setup:** I'm using a cheap [Hikvision 2032](http://www.hikvision.com/en/products_show.asp?id=7326) IP-camera, which is set to IP 192.168.1.199. Its mainstream (H264) is:

**rtsp://192.168.1.199:554/ISAPI/streaming/channels/101?auth=YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=**

(It is working fine in VLC)

As I've been told Motion unfortunately doesn't supports H264 in its current stable release (3.2.12). But the latest developers build has some integration and that there is a fork which is optimized for it.

The installation of the builds is highly complicated though and I try to collect the tips I get in step-by-step instructions in my posting below:

**Edit:**
At this stage I've downloaded the Git Version MrDave recommended me below and I think I have all dependencies. After following the steps in my collected instructions it finally works at 1080x720 resolution.

I have the problem to save files to my images folder when using 1920x1080:

```
nuc@nuc:/usr/local/etc$ motion
[0] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /usr/local/etc/motion.conf
[0] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "sdl_threadnr"
[0] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Motion trunkREVUNKNOWN Started
[0] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to syslog
[0] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Using log type (ALL) log level (NTC)
[0] [NTC] [ENC] ffmpeg_init: ffmpeg LIBAVCODEC_BUILD 3562596 LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD 3555176
[0] [NTC] [ALL] main: Thread 1 is from /usr/local/etc/motion.conf
[0] [NTC] [ALL] main: Thread 1 is device: rtsp://192.168.1.199:554/ISAPI/streaming/channels/101?auth=YWRtaW46MTIzNDU= input -1
[0] [NTC] [ALL] main: Stream port 8081
[0] [NTC] [ALL] main: Waiting for threads to finish, pid: 9028
[1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_init: Thread 1 started , motion detection Enabled
[1] [ALR] [NET] netcam_start: Network Camera thread starting... for url (rtsp://192.168.1.199:554/ISAPI/streaming/channels/101?auth=YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=)
[0] [NTC] [STR] httpd_run: motion-httpd testing : IPV4 addr: 127.0.0.1 port: 8080
[0] [NTC] [STR] httpd_run: motion-httpd Bound : IPV4 addr: 127.0.0.1 port: 8080
[0] [NTC] [STR] httpd_run: motion-httpd/trunkREVUNKNOWN running, accepting connections
[0] [NTC] [STR] httpd_run: motion-httpd: waiting for data on 127.0.0.1 port TCP 8080
[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_rtsp_open_context: Using tcp transport
[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_connect_rtsp: Camera connected
[1] [NTC] [ALL] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] [ALR] [NET] netcam_handler_loop: Camera handler thread [2] started
[1] [NTC] [STR] http_bindsock: motion-stream testing : IPV4 addr: 127.0.0.1 port: 8081
[1] [NTC] [STR] http_bindsock: motion-stream Bound : IPV4 addr: 127.0.0.1 port: 8081
[1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_init: Started motion-stream server in port 8081 auth Disabled
Memoryaccesserror (core image written).
```

The avi and jpg in full resolution are empty or not availabe if I try to open.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what "motion" is? I'm assuming it is some software, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the rtsp and H264 support, you will need to build the application from source.  The primary version of the source is at https://github.com/sackmotion.  There are however many forks of this source the implement various features including RTSP/H264.  If you review the graphs / network tabs in git you can see these versions and determine which is best for your situation.  If you are not familiar with building from source, basic instructions for compiling and building motion can be found in the following fork https://github.com/Mr-Dave/motion in the INSTALL file.  Those instructions have been validated with 12.04 but may require slight modifications for use with 14.04.

Note that for the camera you have referenced, the command line that you reference may not be correct.  The formats that I have observed for this camera are `rtsp://user:pwd@ipaddress:554/streaming/channels/1` (for the primary stream) or `rtsp://user:pwd@ipaddress:554/streaming/channels/2` for the secondary stream.  Prior to setting up the camera in motion, you should  validate the connection string with VLC or avplay.  Once it is confirmed to work in either of those applications, you can copy the connect string directly over into the `motion.conf` file as the netcam url.

Finally, if you want to save CPU resources for this camera, it's better to have motion set up to monitor the smaller SD secondary stream and use the configuration options to trigger an external recording application to record the main HD stream in the native format when motion occurs.

Comment: I don't see any forks to download, maybe I have to sign in? Doesnt the latest build of motion include it? I'm indeed unfamiliar with building from source. --- I don't see anything with your stated stream. I will receive video in VLC if I enter "rtsp://192.168.1.199:554/ISAPI/streaming/channels/101?auth=YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=". --- Which external application would this be?

Comment: `nuc@nuc:~$  git clone {https://github.com/Ken-M/motion}
Klone nach 'motion}'...
fatal: I don't handle protocol '{https'
nuc@nuc:~$`

Comment: As I recall, the daily build you downloaded should generally work but does have a few issues with memory leaks that would be resolved with the version from git.  Regarding the git statement above, enter it just as git clone

Comment: http://github.com/ken-m/motion without the {}.  Next, you will need to install FFMPEG or LIBAV.  The easiest way to do this is via apt as specified within the INSTALL file.  The lack of these libraries being installed is what the configure messages are indicating.

Comment: I tried to collect your informations in a step-to-step guide for Ubuntu 14.04. This is also the current point where I hang as it stands. When I try to configure motion I don't get ffmpeg support. I posted the whole terminaloutput of this stage in my original question above.

Comment: Since you installed Libav via apt, you should be able to use just `./configure` without any additional options.  On your step by step, you need to do steps 2 OR 3 but not both.  I will update the instructions for all future users of my fork.

Comment: okay, so Libav is another ffmpeg version? I did as you said an now receive some errors when I do `make` and `sudo make install`. I posted terminal outputs above and changed my step guide according to your information. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you got caught between the competing versions. Run `sudo apt-get install libswscale-dev` to resolve that build problem

Comment: It seemed to work, pls double check above. In the tutorial it says: sudo cp /etc/motion/motion.conf ~/.motion/motion.conf is this still correct? Because on the end of the installation the directory where I had to rename the motion-dist.conf to motion.conf was in /usr/local/etc. Thanks.

Comment: you should not need to copy that file and just edit the file referenced as being used from your edit:  /usr/local/etc/motion.conf.  Now as you set it up, it is best to edit the file and turn daemon off so that you can see in the terminal any messages.  By default, I believe that the web view is enabled so try going to `localhost:8081` on the computer that is running motion with your web browser and it should show an image.  If it does, it is up and working.  If it doesn'tturn daemon off in the config and report what is displayed when you start it.

Comment: Thank you. I think they did this in the tutorial to avoid that one accidentally destroys the file, but on the other hand it adds a layer of complexity. (Maybe you could create a python script to reset it just for this case?). If I start motion with my URL above (login parameters won't work or we are using a wrong format) I get a mini stream, nice. Now I have to set it to 1920x1080. Doesn't deamon on just start motion if the computer is running? When will the next steable release with this become available? And what would you use to record on motion?

Comment: Something with saving files to my (Bilder directoriy) images doesn't work. I post the memory access error above.

Comment: The core dump at 1920x1080 resolution will be logged as new bug for resolution on my fork.  Note that you will probably have to reboot after the seg fault crash to free the port 8081.  In the interim, I recommend a maximum of 1080x720.  Regarding the other questions, I think that your original question has been answered and the other questions may be better posed to the motion mailing list, launchpad, as an issue related to documentation and FAQ on my fork or a new question here.

Comment: BTW: There seems to be another bug: It will record 8 jpgs and one .avi on every startup without any motion occuring. (Threshold 30000, area detection 5, framerate 2, locate on - it draws a locate frame, after that it works as usual and the frame is more or less on the area of movement).

Comment: It's been a year. Has the support eventually been integrated into the standard-motion package?

Comment: I have not seen that happen yet.  Depending upon your needs, these install from source instructions may still be the best option.

Comment: Oh, this are slow development cycles :) Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

I summarize MrDaves instruction for Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 in a step by step guide:

Motion needs many libraries which need to be installed **before** we can install Motion.:

**Firstly**, we have to install the **required packages for Motion**:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake build-essential libtool libjpeg8-dev libzip-dev
```

**Secondly**, we have to install the **LIBAV libraries**:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev libav-tools libswscale-dev
```

**Important: This optional third step is only needed if you haven't installed LIBAV libraries** (the seconds step): Then we have to install **FFMPEG libraries** from source:

Goto https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html and get the latest source for Ubuntu (via Git):

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd ~
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
```

And build it from source (I haven't found any easy instructions).

**Easier alternative for step 3**: As written [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219550) one can **use apt-get:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install frei0r-plugins
```

After all this we **finally** can install **Motion** via Git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/your_favorite_fork
```

(Motion seems developed in a rather competing fashion with many forks, so you have to check which version fits best for you by looking [at their development tree on Git](https://github.com/sackmotion/motion/network).)

```
example: git clone https://github.com/Ken-M/motion
```

change into the motion folder of your homedrive:

```
cd motion
```

Configure a basic setup:

The command by using the LIBAV route (second step) is:

```
./configure
```

And without LIBAV:

```
./configure --with-ffmpeg=$HOME/ffmpeg --with-ffmpeg-headers=$HOME/ffmpeg/include
```

Now enter:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Goto the directory of the conf file and rename the conf file:

```
cd /usr/local/etc
sudo mv motion-dist.conf motion.conf
```

Finally start motion:

```
motion
```